# Intuition $C^*$-identity

Tags: functional-analysis, intuition

Let X be a Banach algebra and $x,y\in X$ by definition then
$\Vert xy\Vert\leq\Vert x\Vert \Vert y\Vert$
and the intuition could be that it makes multiplication continuous, which is a nice property.

Is there an similar intuition behind the $C^*$-identity? I know it implies that the involution is an isometry, but if that was what was wanted it would seem more direct to just assume that.

Comment: C*-algebras where invented as generalization of closed *-subalgebras of $\mathcal{B}(H)$. As it turns out later they are are exactly closed *-subalgebras of some $\mathcal{B}(H)$. The reason of introducing $C^*$-identity is that it is quite restrictive, intertwine norm involution and multiplication of the $C^*$-algebras and the most important it holds for any operator in $\mathcal{B}(H)$

Comment: Maybe because it relates the spectrum to the norm so again connects algebraic properties with topological ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjoint is an operation which depends on the inner-product. Adjoint is not a purely algebraic concept; nor is it purely topological. Adjoint depends on the inner-product. A non-unitary change of basis for square matrices changes the adjoint, and you can work out what that looks like. You could study an operator algebra on a Hilbert space where you use an adjoint involution generated by one inner-product, and an operator norm generated by another topologically equivalent inner-product.

The $C^{\star}$ identity becomes a consistency condition between the inner-product used to generator the operator norm and the inner-product used to generate the involution.